# Modify private variable of a function with another function

Tags: javascript

Given the following function:

```
function countdown() {
  var result = "";

  // do something with the result variable

  return result;
}
```

How can `result` variable be updated from within another function, before calling the countdown function?

```
function something(){
   // update private variable "result"
}
```

Comment: you can't... I think that is what is the meaning of private(local)...

Comment: Can pass result as arguments to something(result) ?

Comment: Private variables are not meant to be modified.

Comment: If you can modify the functions then pass result as a parameter to `countdown`

Comment: this is not 'private' but local, and you can't.

Comment: if you want to edit it externally, then why not have a public property?

Comment: it can't be passed as a parameter nor declared as a global variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable result is private, and cannot be accessed from the outside.
One solution is to wrap the whole thing in a factory:

```
function countdownFactory () {
  var result = 0;//since its named countdown i assumed it should be a number
  return {
   get: function () { return countdown},
   set: function (value) {countdown = value}
  };
}
```

To use this you would do:

```
var countdown = countdownFactory();
countdown.set(2);
countdown.get() // returns 2
```

Comment: While most of you answered that the local variables can't be modified, but not as an answer but a comment, I'll mark this answer as accepted(as it mention that private variables can'd be modified from outside the scope). Thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 1):

```js
function countdown(modifiedResult) {
  var result = "";

  // do something with the result variable
  result = modifiedResult;

  return result;
}


function something(modifiedResult){
  // update private variable "result"
   var updatedResult = countdown(modifiedResult);
   alert(updatedResult);
}
something("I am updated value");
```

Comment: the main function(countdown) can't be altered in any way

Answer (score 0):

A closure should do it, but you need some access to the function. Here in this case it is `countdown.setResult()`, which puts the value to private variable `result`.

```js
var countdown = function () {
    var result = '';
    function countdown() {
        return result;
    }
    countdown.setResult = function (r) {
        result = r;
    };
    return countdown;
}();

function something(){
    countdown.setResult(42);
}

alert(countdown()); // empty string
something();        
alert(countdown()); // 42
```